# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\w-classes\class.functions.php on line 17

Tags: php

So I went working on my page system, and so appears, it takes to long... I'm not looking to extend the loading time, I'm thinking that there's somethinng wrong.

class.functions.php (Line 16 to 28)

```
public function existingPage($pageid) {
        $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT id FROM ' . $this->prefixed('pages') . ' WHERE id = ?');
        if(!$stmt) {
            throw new Exception($this->mysqli->error, 1);
        }
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $pageid);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Class.functions.php (Line 35 to 41)

```
public function getPage($pageid) {
        if(!$this->existingPage($pageid)) {
            $this->getPage(404);
        } else {
            return new Page($pageid);
        }
    }
```

If you guys need any more code, say so please.

Thanks.

Comment: I would extend the time ( to about 2-3 min ), you have database connection, the timeout to connect to the database may be shorter then 30 sec so you get the php timeout, when you should get one for the DB, with a properly indexed table, pulling by id the query should take a fraction of a second to run, and I see not loops here that would go infinite or such..

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix So now I get `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes)` Any help from your side?

Comment: seem like you have an infinite loop !
check out your loops or break conditions !

Comment: Do you have any while loops running somewhere, you have 128mb set you could do ini_set('memory_limit', '256M') and see if you still have the memory error, chances are there is an errant loop somewhere, or you are pulling more out of the db then you want, did you try the query in phpmyadmin and see the time it take to run just the sql.

Comment: my feeling is existingPage() is being executed within a loop. in which case you would be better with a single query and loop over the result-set.

Answer (score 0):

seems like your loops have no end and they are accumulating duplicate data until memory is exhausted!
So check you while or for loops, and surely break conditions .